# Регистрация ocx -компонента в EmbarCadero RAD Studio 11

Tags: delphi, embarcadero

Возникла такая проблема... Имеется устройство для оцифровки подписи Topaz e-Signatures T-S261HSB. (https://www.topazsystems.com/software/sigplus.exe). после установки и стандартной процедуры регистрации ocx-компонента: Component -> Import Component... -> Import ActiveX Control -> SigPlus OLE Control module в палитре компонентов появляется сам компонент и после помещения его на форму приложение компилируется. Но если в Target Platforms добавить Windows x64 то при попытке поместить этот же компонент на форму возникает ошибка "Класс не зарегистрирован". Установка 64 разрядной версии (https://www.topazsystems.com/software/sigplus64_44157.exe) этого компонента проблемы не решает всё равно пишет "Класс не зарегистрирован". Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно зарегистрировать ocx-компонент именно под 64 разрядное приложение.

Comment: попробовать деинсталировать и потом установить только 64-разрядную версию.

Comment: Всем спасибо, вопрос решен!

Comment: "вопрос решен" слишком коротко. Пожалуйста напиши в чем была проблема и как ты понял, что именно в этом проблема.

Comment: проблема была в том, что я пытался 64 разрядный компонент откомпилировать и установить (пункт меню install)рядом с 32 разрядным в итоге в дереве компонентов появлялся компонент TSignPlus доступный в windows x32 и windows x64  но после перемещения вышеуказанного компонента на форму происходила ошибка "класс не зарегистрирован". Как оказалось нужно было сначала установить сначала 32 разрядную версию откомпилировать и установить а 64 разрядную нужно было только откомпилировать и всё.